# How to project on a repeating attribute

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational, relational-algebra

Using relational algebra, I have to retrieve the list of employees that have a salary that is greater than the salary of the manager of the department for which they work.

I have the following 2 tables:

EMPLOYEE

```
Fname | Minit | Lname | **SSN** | BDate | Address | Sex | Salary | SupervSSN | DeprtNo
```

DEPARTMENT

```
Dname | Dnumber | MgrSSN | MgrStartDate
```

Where `DeprtNo` points to `Dnumber` and `MgrSSN` points to `SSN`.

The way I attempted this query was as follows:

```
MGRS ← (EMPLOYEE) |><| MgrSSN = SSN (DEPARTMENT) //All Manager employees
EMPS ← (EMPLOYEE) |><| MgrSSN != SSN (DEPARTMENT)//All non-managers employees
EM   ← (EMPS) |><| DeprtNo = DeprtNo (MGRS)      //Managers are joined with non-managers who work in their Department.
```

Now I want to Project just the Manager SSN's based on a select that compares the manager's salary with the non-manager's salary. However, EM contains Repeating categories - SSN and Salary. Once for the managers and once for the non-managers. SO I don't know how to project correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
select MgrSSN from Department where 
Dnumber in (
  select DeprtNo from Employee where
  SSN not in (select Employee.SSN  from Employee inner join Department on Employee.SSN = Department.MgrSSN)
  and Salary > (select min(Employee.Salary) from Employee inner join Department on Employee.SSN = Department.MgrSSN)
)
```

I think this should be able to project the MgrSSN of the departments where there exists an employee whose salary is greater than the manager.